# OpenGL DrawArrays with Color

Tags: opengl-es, jogl, opengl-2.0

I'm currently using OpenGL2 for one of my projects and I want to render a PointCloud. I can also already display the points at the correct positions but I have a problem with the colors.
This is my Code:

```
public void draw(DrawContext drawContext){

        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        int stride = 0;

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO.get(0));

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, stride, 0);

        gl.glColorPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, stride,vertBuf.limit());

        gl.glPointSize(4);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertBuf.limit());

        gl.glPointSize(1);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    }
```

The position and color values are both in one VBO(the one that I bind). But I don't know how the call to DrawArrays has to look like so it actually uses the color values. Currently, when the points are rendered they are just grey as if I hadn't assigned a color to them. I know this would be easy with shaders but I can not use them. I have to do it this way.
The positions are saved in a FloatBuffer called `vertBuf` and the colors in a FloatBuffer called `colorBuffer`. The colorValues are also normalized between 0 and 1 and are in RGB if that matters.

I bind the position and color values to the VBO like this:

```
gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,(vertBuf.limit()*4)+(colorBuffer.limit()*4),null, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
gl.glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,vertBuf.limit(),vertBuf)
gl.glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertBuf.limit(),colorBuffer.limit(),colorBuffer)
```

Comment: Rather ask this question on the official JogAmp forum as it might be very specific to JOGL.

Comment: Post a SSCCE instead of a piece of code.

Comment: Hey @gouessej :) Thanks for answering. Sadly, I currently don't have access to the code I will have to post it next Monday. I will also post it to the JogAmp forum. To your comment under Rabbid76 answer: You are correct I indeed used the wrong parameter for DrawArrays. Doesn't it have to be ```vertbuf.limit()/3```? Or am I understanding something wrong? ^^ Regarding the example you posted: I guess I can't use that because I can't use Shaders in WorldWind(which I am using). Anyway thanks for always answering my questions and trying to help me :D.

Comment: I did something similar in T.U.E.R which doesn't use shaders: http://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuer/code/alpha/drawer/StaticVertexBufferObject.java but I didn't use a VAO and I used an interleaved VBO. Use GL_C3F_V3F as interleaved format and put the colors before the vertices into your direct NIO buffers, call `gl.glInterleavedArrays(GL2.GL_C3F_V3F,0 ,0);`, don't forget the rest, `rewind()`, ... Then, it's rather `vertbuf.limit() / 6`.

Comment: @gouessej I posted my question on the [JogAmp Forum](http://forum.jogamp.org/OpenGL2-Can-t-render-points-with-color-td4040994.html) I guess we can continue there ^^;.

Answer (score 1):

The last argument of `glColorPointer` is the buffer offset **in bytes**. So the offset `vertBuf.limit() * 4` and not `vertBuf.limit()`:

<s>`gl.glColorPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, stride, vertBuf.limit());`</s>

```java
gl.glColorPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, stride, vertBuf.limit()*4);
```

The *offset* and *size* argument of `glBufferSubData` also specifies the buffer offset and buffer size **in bytes**:

<s>`gl.glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,vertBuf.limit(),vertBuf)`</s>
<s>`gl.glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertBuf.limit(),colorBuffer.limit(),colorBuffer)`</s>

```java
gl.glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertBuf.limit()*4, vertBuf);
gl.glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf.limit()*4, colorBuffer.limit()*4, colorBuffer);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer :) You are right that's a mistake and I think I did the same thing wrong when I set the BufferSubData or not? It's not supposed to be ```vertBuf.limit()``` but ```vertBuf.limit()*4``` or not? And the same thing with the colorBuffer of course. I changed my code accordingly but the points still have a grey Color. Is there maybe something wrong with my ```glDrawArrays()``` call?

Comment: @FieryToken The offset and the size must be specified in bytes. I've extended the answer.

Comment: hmm yes I have tried it out but it's still just grey. :/

Comment: @FieryToken Rabbid76 is right. By the way, you can use our official example: https://jogamp.org/cgit/jogl-demos.git/tree/src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java?id=HEAD Look at numBytes. Look at the documentation of glDrawArrays too: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml Your last parameter is wrong, you don't pass the number of indices to be rendered.